# Minimum entropy decomposition of probability distributions

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mixture-distribution

Say you want to decompose a probability distribution (a PDF) into a mixture of distributions in such a way as to minimize the mean entropy of the component distributions. I have an idea that this is achieved iff the mixture components are Gaussian. Can this be proven?

Comment: Don't you mean *maximize* the mean entropy??  Regardless, such a decomposition is impossible in general unless you allow the weights to be negative. Consider decomposing a uniform distribution into a mixture of Gaussians, for instance: if all weights are positive, then the support of the mixture is the entire real line, whereas the support of any uniform distribution is compact.

Comment: @whuber No I mean minimize - if I wanted to maximize the entropy my mixture would have one component equal to the original PDF, as mixture distributions can never have larger mean entropy than their combined distribution. For the purposes of the question we can assume the support of the original PDF is the real line, although I believe you can approximate even a uniform distribution arbitrarily closely with a mixture of gaussians.

Comment: Do you have some references/links to this idea? Examples where it has been used? Do you mean something like [Mixtures of Gaussians and Minimum Relative Entropy Techniques for
Modeling Continuous Uncertainties](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.1476.pdf)?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen yes, but that paper just describes a way of fitting a finite Gaussian mixture to an arbitrary PDF. This paper is a bit closer to the mark, although it is about finding the entropy of a mixture when you know the entropy of the components which is kind of the inverse to my problem: https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/19/7/361